# IIS server increase users

Tags: asp.net, iis

In IIS 7, I was told that only a certain number of clients can access the system because of the defualt setting. I currently have 100 clients and only 10 can us the system that i have created and would like to know how i could increase the total number of clients that can access my asp.net application

Comment: You can't increase the number of users above infinity! Please rewrite your question so it makes sense :) Also, this question is off-topic and would be better suited to ServerFault.com.

Comment: i have changed the question

Comment: What happens when the 11th user attempts to use the application? Is it that only 10 *concurrent* users can access your application, or is it that 10 specific clients can always access, and the other 90 never can. Please be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim, may I know what Operating System do you use? If you're using Windows Server OS, there should be no problem with the number of users that can access your application. But if you're using Windows client OS like XP, Vista, 7 then you have limits with simultaneous connections to your web server.

Comment: I use windows server 2008R so what would the limit be in terms of number of users can access the site, also the website is deployed on a server.

Comment: There should be no limitation in terms of number of connections or the number of simultaneous connections in your application if you're running IIS on Windows Server 2008. The only limitation is the upload file size (by default that's only 30MB).